# Filter Array in Ruby on Rails with only to_s elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code that works well

```
def self.select_some_elements(some_value)
   return elements.select { |element| element.some_value > some_value}
end
```

This code returns an array of elements class instances/objects. However, I would like to return the array of element.to_s instances/propeties, not the whole class objects, just strings/string properties

Is there a quick way to do it without going extra steps?

Comment: It's often easier to provide a minimal code example to show what you want, i.e. an example array, your current output and the expected output.

Comment: Also note that your question doesn't seem Rails-specific. If the elements you are working with are actually Rails models (just guessing), you should say so. Maybe the filtering / attribute selection could be delegated to the database layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Introduction:**

So, what you have achieved is a set (array in this case) of objects, which is great. What you have to do now is to transform this set into a different one: namely, replace each object with what that object's method `to_s` returns. There's a perfect method for that, called [map](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/map). It goes through all the items, calls a block with each item as an argument and puts in the resulting array what the block has returned:

Open `irb` console and play around:

```
>> [1,2,3].map{|x| 1}
=> [1, 1, 1]
>> [1,2,3].map{|x| x+1}
=> [2, 3, 4]
>> [1,2,3].map{|x| "a"}
=> ["a", "a", "a"]
>> [1,2,3].map{|x| x.to_s}
=> ["1", "2", "3"]
>> [1,2,3].map(&:to_s)
=> ["1", "2", "3"]
```

The last transformation seems to be what you need:

**The answer:**
Add `.map(&:to_s)` at the end like this

```
def self.select_some_elements(some_value)
   return elements.select { |element| element.some_value > some_value}.map(&:to_s)
end
```

`.map(&:to_s)` is a short version of `.map { |element| element.to_s }`. And you can [read about Arra3#map in the docs](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/map)

And when you wrap your head around the `#map`, check out [Stefan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69334336/299774) which shows how `select{}.map` can be "compressed" into one `filter_map` call (doing both things: filter, and mapping in one iteration over the set instead of two).

Comment: For the OP's sake, please note that the `return` is redundant. In Ruby, a method returns the last expression in it.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Ruby 2.7 there's [`filter_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#filter_map-method):

```
elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

elements.filter_map { |e| e.to_s if e > 2 }
#=> ["3", "4", "5"]
```